# os.walk finds files that don't exist

Tags: python, file, path

I was creating a program that checked for files in my Downloads folder and moved them in some subfolders depending on their extention.

I used `os.walk("path")`         `# path is the path to my downloads folder`
and printed the files it found, just to see if it worked.

The problem is that the program finds the files in the folder, but it also finds some files that aren't there, most of them end with .zpa, and it also finds a desktop.ini file.

Is this normal or is there something wrong?

Comment: Those files are hidden in the graphical file explorer.

Comment: You could try `os.stat` on the files to see if they are hidden.

Comment: The files are there, just have the hidden flag set.  `os.walk` finds all files.  From the command line "dir /a" in the folder will show all files.  `dir /ah` will show only hidden files.

Comment: How exactly do determine that these files are not in your folder?

Comment: @Barmar ok I looked up how to see hidden files and the ones ending in .zpa are showing now, desktop.ini isn't though.    How exactly do this files become hidden?

Comment: Since that's an internal file used by the desktop manager, it hides it itself.

Comment: There's some Explorer option to show hidden files — turn it on.

Comment: desktop.ini is also marked as a system file, and those are hidden by default as well.  Run `attrib desktop.ini` in the Downloads folder to see all its attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.walk` will find all files including those marked with hidden and system attributes.  Those files are not displayed by default in the Windows Explorer or the command line `dir` utility.

If you want to skip hidden and system files in Python you'll have to check for the file attributes:

```py
import os
import stat

for path,dirs,files in os.walk('Downloads'):
    for file in files:
        filename = os.path.join(path,file)
        info = os.stat(filename)
        if not info.st_file_attributes & (stat.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM | stat.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN):
            print(filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

See `os.walk` finds all files inside a directory. Those files which are hidden in Windows file explorer are also found out by this. Hidden files can include

- Files hidden by you from within file explorer
- Files hidden by OS itself, which are OS specific configuration files which we don't have to worry much about.
- Files hidden by any application software intentionally

Probably there can be files from the above category which you got to see in the output.

As far as `.zpa` files are concerned, I don't know about those, but found a [link](https://fileinfo.com/extension/zpa) which could help you.